# android- static variable is renewed when service is recalled?

Tags: android, variables, service, static

I have a question about the static variable in service.

I write the code like below.

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    private String $previousNotificationTimestamp = "GodLovesYou";
    private static boolean $broadcastReceiverRegistered = false;

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent _intent, int _flags, int _startId) {

}
```

The service is running now, but if service get recalled by the intent, it runs the `onStartCommand()` method not `onCreate()` method.

In that situation, Service renews the static variable value???
(it means $broadcastReceiverRegistered = false)

Comment: I have improved your question as it was possible, could you please make it more clear to understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can define variables in activity for keep its value. Or you can define variables in Constants.cs for global use. When you recall service you create new service in this way you can't keep static variable value.